# enum class and global operator~ overloading

Tags: c++11

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct D
{
  template <class T> D (T);
};
int operator~(const D &);

template <typename T> T &make ();

template <typename Rhs> struct H
{
  static const int value = sizeof ~make<Rhs>();
};

enum class E;

int main () { return H<E>::value; }
```

Is this valid C++11?

Clang accepts it. Gcc gives an error:

```cpp
 % gcc -std=c++11 b.ii
b.ii: In instantiation of ‘const int H<E>::value’:
b.ii:16:28:   required from here
b.ii:11:35: error: no match for ‘operator~’ (operand type is ‘E’)
   static const int value = sizeof ~make<Rhs>();
```

The code was reduced from a gcc bug report: 
    http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60852

This is the unreduced test case:

```cpp
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <iostream>

enum class E {};

int main()
{ std::cout << boost::has_complement<E>() << std::endl; }
```

Comment: No error with GCC 4.6.3

Comment: I don't know, for g++4.8, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a9768812b936ae3) compiles but not [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68922068a64e22f9)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is rejected since gcc-4.8. Intel's icpc also rejects the code.

Comment: A better title for this question would be good...

Comment: Clang [fixed](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19452).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC is right here, scoped enumeration, aka `enum class` are not implicitly converting to int or anything else. By extension, they do not have a built-in `operator~`, so you need to cast explicitly :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class E { val };

int main () { 
    std::cout << ~std::underlying_type<E>::type(E::val);
}
```

By removing your `struct D` and the global `operator~`, clang give the good error. It is a bug clearly as `operator~(D)` is not a candidate in the first place :

```
main.cpp:17:35: error: invalid argument type 'E' to unary expression
static const int value = sizeof ~make<Rhs>();
```

The rules about collecting the overloads § 13.3.1.2 :

> For a unary operator @ with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualified
>   version is T1, [...], three sets of candidate functions, designated
>   member candidates, nonmember
>       candidates and built-in candidates, are constructed as follows:

And the finish :

> However, if no operand has a class type, only those non-member
>   functions in the lookup set that have a first parameter of type T1 or
>   reference to (possibly cv-qualified) T1”, when T1 is an enumeration
>   type, [...], are candidate functions.

To summarize, because E is of non class type, only free function operators taking a E or a reference to E are considered.

Comment: But since `make<E>()` returns an `E`, and `D` is constructible from `E` and defines an `operator ~()`, shouldn't that operator be applicable? (Not saying you're wrong here, just asking.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi clang is wrong to consider the operator~(D) in the first place as demonstrate by the standard quote i added in the edit.